# How to trigger build by tag on a specific branch on jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, github, pipeline

I have setted up a Jenkins job that triggers whenever a tag is pushed, but I need it to trigger only when a tag is created on master branch.

I have a problem when I clean the node from Jenkins it loses all information about tags on github and when someone pushes code to github, Jenkins takes old tags and build them again even though the push was made on a different branch.

If I set up Branch specifier on Jenkins job to trigger on **/tags/** and add another Branch specifier */master is it going to combine the Branch specifier to trigger only if both statements are TRUE (so if I create a tag on master) or is it going to trigger if at least one of them is TRUE (if I create a tag or if a normal push on master) ?

If it doesn't combine, how to combine the statements ? Is there a way of creating a pipeline to trigger that way ?

Comment: Your best bet is to create a convention around tag names.On master you use a pattern. Other places some different pattern.